# Matching two columns based on the value of some column in a different table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

With a very limited knowledge of sql fighting to solve this query for last couple of hours:

```
Table: Airport
Code    Country
----    -------
JFK     USA
ARN     Sweden
UMU     Sweden
LAX     USA
BER     Germany


Table: Flight
Origin    Destination
------    -----------
LAX       JFK
ARN       JFK
UMU       ARN
JFK       BER
```

The problem is to find the Airport which runs Domestic flight only, i.e, the destination airport is in the same country as the origin airport. The query is suppose to produce the following result:

```
 DomesticAirport
 ---------------
 LAX
 UMU
```

A little help will be highly appriciated

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL or Postgres?  And what have you tried?  Please edit your question with an example of the SQL you have attempted.

Comment: The effort doesnot look good at all...  SELECT Flight.Origin FROM Flight, Airport WHERE Flight.Origin=Airport.Code AND Airport.Country IN (SELECT Airport.Country FROM Flight, Airport WHERE Flight.Destination=Airport.Code) GROUP BY Flight.Origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This results in your desired output:

```
select f.origin
  from flight f
  join airport a1
    on f.origin = a1.code
  join airport a2
    on f.destination = a2.code
 where a1.country = a2.country
```

**SQL Fiddle demo here:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92363/5/0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "run domestic flights" you mean that flights *originating* at the airport are all domestic, then you can do this by finding the countries for the `origin` and `destination` using two `join`s.  Then aggregate the result by the original airport and use a `having` clause to filter the airports you want.

```
select f.origin
from flights f join
     airport ao
     on f.origin = ao.origin join
     airport ad
     on f.destination = ad.destination
group by f.origin, ao.country
having min(ad.country) = ao.country and max(ad.country) = ao.country
```